# when user clicks on my notification i want to show an AlertDialog there

Tags: android, android-notifications

how can i show an AlertDialog in my activity, when the notification is clicked in notification area.
plz help....
i'm using multiple status bar notifications each with unique IDS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put some data to signal that an `AlertDialog` should be shown into a `PendingIntent` and put this into `yourNotification.contentIntent` of your notification. Display the `AlertDialog` from your `Activity` in case it receives this `Intent`.

Have a look at the [Notifications Doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html).

Answer (score 1):

I've solved a similar problem by having the notification intent open a new activity with a transparent background.  The activity then spawns the AlertDialog.